# sync htc / android phone with macbook / mac os x

Tags: 2.2-froyo, sync, htc-wildfire, macos

I use MacBook (which have Mac OS X 10.6 - Snow Leopard). How can I sync data between my HTC phone and my MacBook.

I have HTC Wildfire, and HTC Sync software only supports Windows.

Comment: Well...Don't Macs have the ability to run Windows via BootCamp?

Comment: @Sparx: Macs do have ability to run Windows, but I don't want Windows on my MacBook

Answer (score 3):

As of now, there's no counterpart on Mac for HTC Sync.

You can however try [MissingSync for Mac](http://www.markspace.com/products/android/missing-sync-android.html) - which allows for syncing of contacts, calendars, notes, tasks etc. on Mac

Answer (score 2):

It's not recommended to even attempt to do syncing Windows. Android have a very different design than, say, an iPhone; Android is designed to sync over the air with cloud services like Google Contact, Gmail, Google Calendar, etc. In Android, you shouldn't need to tie your device with a computer. What you need is a Wifi or 3G connection, and you don't need to worry about syncing.

Comment: Well said...however a lot of people feel better about having their data stored locally and not on the cloud. In the end, it all boils down to user choice. :-)

Answer (score 1):

For data not including contacts, email, etc since they're already synced for you thru Gmail... you could try Dropbox or some other cloud service. [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) would appear as a folder on your computer (Mac or Windows), and Dropbox would run as an [app](http://market.android.com/details?id=com.dropbox.android) on your phone. So, whatever files/data you have in the folder on your computer would be accessible from your phone, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sync media files, I suggest you to connect your device in Storage mode or use [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/). If you mean that you want to sync contacts, appointments and this kind of stuff, just migrate all that information to Google Contacts, Calendar and others using iCal and Contacts on your Mac.

If you really want something like HTC Sync you have two options:

- Install HTC Sync on a Windows using Bootcamp
- Pay for [MissingSync for Mac](http://www.markspace.com/products/android/missing-sync-android.html)